# Repaint function

Tags: java, swing, graphics, repaint

I need some help with repaint() function. When I run the program it's makes a image flashing effect. What's wrong?

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Game() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Images/bg.jpg"),0,0,this);
        g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Images/player.png"),0,448,this);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game langas = new Game();
        langas.setSize(900,550);
        langas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        langas.setTitle("Best Game EVER! LOL");
        langas.setVisible(true);
        langas.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        langas.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English and sorry if my code look stupid I am beginner.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: I testing this function. I want to know how it's work.

Comment: @Zeb Sometimes you just go speechless.

Comment: @Kayaman Fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote an endless recursion, because:

`repaint` calls `paint`, which calls `repaint`, which calls `paint`,...

You're caught in a repaint loop, therefore the image is flickering.

Comment: Ohh... Now I understand that. Thank you :).